# Whats wrong with this java code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

main class

```
package other;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    JFrameClass obj = new JFrameClass();
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.setSize(275, 180);
    obj.setVisible(true);
}
```

my gui class

```
package other;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameClass extends JFrame {

    // t1 -text 1 
    private JLabel t1;

    public JFrameClass(){

        super("Gui");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        t1 = new JLabel("This is sentencw");
        t1.setToolTipText("HoverText");
        add(t1);

    }

}
```

i'm using eclipse and it si giving me a error for the setsize,setdefault...,setvisible methods
i'm getting three or two errors in each one of them
it says syntax error on token "," and like this

Comment: Use a `main` method to call method from objects. You can only initialise object in a `class` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing statements directly into the class body. You should put your code in a method like this:

```
package other;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrameClass obj = new JFrameClass();
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.setSize(275, 180);
    obj.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

This should remove the errors. However, in my opinion you should put the commands within JFrameClass' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor to initialize all variables(it's a good practice also)